# JCarousel and dynamic contents

Tags: jquery, yii, jcarousel

I am using Jquery JCarousal in Yii framework, in one of the views I am loading the images from a model:

```
<ul id="first-carousel" class="first-and-second-carousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
<?php 

    foreach ($news as $newsElement) {
?>  

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $newsElement->url ?>">
        <div class="news-title">
            <p><?php echo $newsElement->title; ?></p>
        </div>
        <img src="<?php  echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().IMAGE_URL.$newsElement->cover->image ?>" width="165" height="165" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>


<?php }?>

</ul>
```

and I am using JCarousal to slide these images, like this:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('carousel',
    "           $('.first-and-second-carousel').jcarousel({
                scroll: 1,  
                animation: 'slow',
            })

     ", CClientScript::POS_READY
    );  ?>
```

I tried this code and it was working fine when I had some static content, but now, only the first `<li>` is getting loaded and the rest are not visible. (I can see them in the source code of the page).

in [JCarousel documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Dynamic-Content-Loading) there are explanations about loading dynamic contents but I didn't know how to use it since I am reading the content from the model, I didn't want to use any of the JCarousal extentions for yii because I needed to make some changes to the source code to make it work with multiple rows... Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Need more info. Did you get any error in the jaascript console? can we see a working example?

Comment: Paste the generated markup into a jsfiddle so we can expect the entire output. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: The thing is that it works, the only problem is that when I read the data in the loop only the first result gets recognized by JCarousel, I think I should add them manually some how, if I just put some static data it works perfectly fine. here is a [link](http://kriptonite-new.linkmesrl.com/it/news/index) to the page. if You check it with firebug you see that there is only one element in the list, if you look at the page source there are 2!!!

Comment: Well, I am making changes so I think the link wouldn't show the same results anymore...

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by changing to Jquery Cycle. I gave up using JCarousel. I think it wasn't the right library for my purpose...